# How to use the contents of a cell to designate the name of a sheet to reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

=IF(B15="Lift Tickets",A15!LiftTickets_Markup1,"")

I'm trying to use cell A15 as the name of the WorkSheet to look for cell(LiftTickets_Markup1).
A15 changes depending on the results of add-in macros.

Since in this case cell A15 = "Alterra" then the formula should look return Alterra!LiftTickets_Markup1

[image shows the excel page and worksheets below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJMbV.png)

Comment: Use the `Indirect` function

Comment: Thanks Chris Nielsen!